# Consecutive numbers with mutually distinct exponents in their canonical prime factorization

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences

Is it possible to find 23 consecutive positive integers each of which has mutually distinct exponents in its canonical prime factorization? Such numbers are sequence [A130091](http://oeis.org/A130091) in OEIS. 24 such numbers are impossible because of $36n-6$ and $36n+6$.

Comment: how long is the longest sequence you know of already?

Comment: An early instance of 5: 16,17,18,19, and 20.

Comment: 4372, 4373, 4374, 4375, 4376 as well.

Comment: 2644, 2645, 2646, 2647, 2648 are another 5.

Comment: You might also mention $1,2,3,4,5$ and $241, 242, 243, 244, 245$.  Those and the ones you listed are all the $5$'s less than $10^6$, and there are no sequences of length $>5$ in this range.

Comment: There are also no such sequences of length $> 5$ less than $10^7$.

Comment: The problem is that most numbers have some prime factor with exponent $1$, while in an interval $\{36n+7,\dots,36n+29\}$ many numbers already have prime factors $2$, $3$ or $5$ with exponent $1$, and therefore by the condition in the question must have all larger factors with higher exponents. This seems like a pretty unlikely constellation.

Comment: Another $5$: $1431124, 1431125, 1431126, 1431127, 1431128$.

Comment: The numbers of the form $4k+2$ in such an interval of length 23 must be two times an odd powerful number. So by dividing by two we obtain at least 10 consecutive powerful odd numbers!

Comment: ...where by $10$ you mean $5$.

Comment: I wonder if one can prove that there are infinitely many pairs (without relying on conjectures, such as about Mersenne primes).

Comment: The only new sequence of length 5, not mentioned above, before $10^8$, starts at 12502348.

Comment: @AdamP.Goucher Oh! You are right.

Comment: Up to $7.0\times 10^8$, the only new 5-tuple of integers starts with $112753348$.  There were no 6-tuples.  I'm stopping my computations now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to this question is almost certainly no.

It is well known that the ABC Conjecture implies that there are only finitely many triples $(n,n+1,n+2)$ which are all powerful.  A similar argument should work for tuples of the form $(2n+1,2n+3,2n+5)$.  But, as pointed out by Mostafa and Adam (in the comments above), a sequence of 23 consecutive integers with the property you want will give rise to too many odd powerful numbers near each other.

---

If you want to see the actual ABC computation: consider any list of 12 consecutive integers $n,n+1,n+2,...,n+11$.  Then three of these numbers are exactly divisible by $2$, say they are $2k-4,2k,2k+4$ for some odd $k$.  Then your condition implies $k-2,k,k+2$ are powerful. In particular, $(k-2)(k+2)=k^2-4$ is powerful.

Apply the ABC conjecture to the triple $(4,k^2-4,k^2)$.  The radical base is at most $2k^{3/2}$, which doesn't beat $c=k^2$.  So, under the conjecture, there can be only finitely many sequences of 12 consecutive integers of the type you want.

Answer (score 9):

We prove that there are only finitely many such intervals.

---

Suppose $[36n + 7, 36n + 29]$ is one such interval.

Now, $36n + 10$ and $36n + 15$ cannot both be divisible by $5$ (since one must occur with multiplicity $1$), hence $n \neq 0 \mod{5}$.

- We can say the same about $36n + 21$ and $36n + 26$ (so $n \neq 4 \mod{5}$).
- And about $36n + 14$ and $36n + 24$ (so $n \neq 1 \mod{5}$).
- And indeed about $36n + 12$ and $36n + 22$ (so $n \neq 3 \mod{5}$).

This implies that $n \equiv 2 \mod{5}$, so $36n + 18$ is divisible by $5$ (and therefore by $25$). So our set must actually be of the form:

$$[900m + 439, 900m + 461]$$

---

**Irrelevant aside**: We can do a similar analysis modulo $7$, enabling us to deduce that precisely one of $900m + 445$, $900m + 450$ and $900m + 455$ is divisible by $49$. This doesn't seem to help as much, though.

Indeed, no generalisation of this argument will work, because only the primes $p \leq 23$ are pertinent (we can just shift the interval with the help of the Chinese Remainder Theorem to avoid large primes completely), and it's possible to find a $23$-element interval in which the multiplicities of each of the primes $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23$ are distinct for each element (left as an exercise to the reader).

---

Let us return to the task of proving that there are only finitely many such intervals. For each interval, either:

- $900m + 440$ and $900m + 456$ are both congruent to $4 \mod{8}$.
- $900m + 444$ and $900m + 460$ are both congruent to $4 \mod{8}$.

In which case we take those two numbers and divide them by $4$ to obtain odd coprime integers $b, b+4$. One of them is divisible by $3$ (but not $3^2$) and the other is divisible by $5$ (but not $5^2$). Any other primes dividing them must do so with multiplicity $\geq 3$, because $2$ divided each of the original numbers with multiplicity $2$.

Whence $(4, b, b+4)$ has a radical less than $k b^{2/3}$ for some universal constant $k$ which I can't be bothered to calculate.

Since the $abc$ conjecture is true, it follows there are only finitely many intervals with your property.

Comment: You write "Since the abc conjecture is true ...": have you checked Mochizuki's proof? -- As far as I know, its correctness is not generally accepted so far (if you have more recent information, you could update the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture)).

Comment: The following paper settles the matter: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12044-016-0326-z